# INSERT statement in SQl

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2007

I am trying to save record in more then one table i am using insert statement but it gives me "syntax error in the INSERT INTO statement"
Here is my code

```
strSQL = " INSERT INTO [2011 Nurse Patient Index]
                (File Number, Patient name ,Gender , AgeRTU , Nationality , 
                 Diagnosis , Other , Appointment , Date)
         VALUES('" & File_NumberRTU.Value & "','" & Patient_nameRTU.Value & "' , 
                '" & GenderRTU.Value & "', '" & AgeRTU.Value & "' , 
                '" & NationalityRTU.Value & "' , '" & DiagnosisRTU.Value & "' ,
                '" & OtherRTU.Value & "' , '" & AppointmentRTU.Value & "' ,
                '" & DateRTU.Value & "')"
        CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
```

the error appears in this line

```
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
```

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?
Thank you

Comment: We need to know what's in the variables that you're using to build the SQL.  The best way is to do Debug.Print strSQL before trying to execute it, and then show use the result of that print statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Date column is of type `Date` or `Datetime` in your database, you may have to surround `DateRTU.Value` with #'s, i.e.,

```
INSERT INTO 
    [2011 Nurse Patient Index]([File Number], [Patient name], Gender, AgeRTU, Nationality, Diagnosis, Other, Appointment, Date) 
VALUES 
    ('" & File_NumberRTU.Value & "', 
     '" & Patient_nameRTU.Value & "', 
     '" & GenderRTU.Value & "', 
     '" & AgeRTU.Value & "', 
     '" & NationalityRTU.Value & "', 
     '" & DiagnosisRTU.Value & "', 
     '" & OtherRTU.Value & "', 
     '" & AppointmentRTU.Value & "', 
     '#" & DateRTU.Value & "#')"
```

Comment: No problem, by the way you should mark an answer as correct by clicking the big checkmark on the left side. This way other people know that the question has been answered and won't waste time clicking it :).

Comment: IT worked once then now it gives me the same error again i don't know why is that and Why did it save the record in the first place

Comment: What do you mean? Of course it is going to 'save' the record in the database - it is inserting a row into it.

Comment: IT did at first when i tried another record it gave me the same error as before" syntax error in the INSERT INTO statement" i don't know why

Comment: It probably has something to do with the actual data you are trying to insert. Store the query string I gave you into a variable and print it out somehow so you can see what SQL it is actually executing for the data that is not working, then post that.

Comment: I got it the is no .Value so for example its "INSERT INTO [2011 Nurse Patient Index]([File Number])VALUES ('" & File_NumberRTU & "')"

Answer (score 1):

Try square brackets around `[File Number]` and `[Patient name]`.

```
strSQL = " INSERT INTO [2011 Nurse Patient Index]([File Number], [Patient name] ,Gender , AgeRTU , Nationality , Diagnosis , Other , Appointment , Date)VALUES('" & File_NumberRTU.Value & "','" & Patient_nameRTU.Value & "' , '" & GenderRTU.Value & "', '" & AgeRTU.Value & "' , '" & NationalityRTU.Value & "' , '" & DiagnosisRTU.Value & "' , '" & OtherRTU.Value & "' , '" & AppointmentRTU.Value & "' , '" & DateRTU.Value & "')"
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
```

Comment: @AyaAbdelsalam What is the value of `strSQL` after the assignment?

Comment: @AyaAbdelsalam Maybe your values contains the `'` char. That will break the statement, and that's why you shouldn't insert to the database using dynamic SQL.

Comment: I got it now acctually there 2 mistake [File Number] and [Patient name] and the date with out # Thanks alot